# How to set the locale inside an Ajax call in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this Ajax function inside my `application.js` file:

```
$("#project_person_id").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/projects/get_invoice_types',
        data: 'person_id=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

Is it possible to use a **locale** inside that function?

When I change line 3 to this:

```
url: '/de/projects/get_invoice_types',
```

I get the desired outcome (i. e. the output in German).

But of course I would like to set this dynamically. How can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set it dynamically wherever you like, i.e

```
var locale = "de"; // set it dynamically
```

and the use it as a global, like this

```
$("#project_person_id").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/"+locale+'/projects/get_invoice_types', // use it
        data: 'person_id=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

a more elegant why would be to set it as a data attribute to the body tag `<body data-locale="de">` or to the HTML head `<html lang="de">`, and pull it using a function

`function locale() { return $("body").data("locale") }` or 
`function locale() { return $("html").attr("lang") }` and then retrieve it like this:

```
$("#project_person_id").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/"+locale()+'/projects/get_invoice_types', // use it
        data: 'person_id=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

there are other options of course, these seem straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue modifying $.get and $.post jQuery's functions.

I my case the locale is a parameter in the url, but it can be injected as *Sagish* did too

```
(function ($) {
  var oPost = jQuery.post;
  var oGet = jQuery.get;

  jQuery.post=function(url , data , success , dataType ){
    if (typeof data === "undefined") {
      data={};
    }
    data=add_locale_to_url(data);
    return oPost.apply(this,[url , data , success , dataType]);
  }  

  jQuery.get=function(url , data , success , dataType ){    
    if (typeof data === "undefined") {
      data={};
    }
    data=add_locale_to_url(data);    
    return oGet.apply(this,[url , data , success , dataType]);
  } 

})(jQuery);
```

And when I call $.get or $.post the locale is automatically added to the URL:

```
...   
var remote_search=$.get("/expenses/search_users/"+$(this).val());

    remote_search(function( data ) {
          $("#processing").hide();
          alert( "Usuari inexistent");
          obj_error.val("");
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding data attributes to my erb template.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="save-job-position-btn" data-locale="<%= params[:locale] %>"><%= t("save") %></button>
```

```
$( "#save-job-position-btn" ).click(function() {
  var locale = $(this).data("locale");
}
```